# Cannot manipulate list integer index

Tags: python, list, matrix, swap

My code does the following, It reads a N*N matrix file e.g. my matrix.txt file is

2 3 4

1 2 6

9 8 9

and converts it into a list integer [[2,3,4],[1,2,6],[9,8,9]]

which
then transposes the values inside by moving the value inside to the value of the index when flipped. E.g. [1][0] = 1, so the value of list [0][1] should change from 3 to 1. and the value of [1][0] changes from 1 to 3.

This makes it so the final output after transposing the matrix should become

[[2,1,9],[3,2,8],[4,6,9]] after flipping all values.

Keep in mind if the index is same where [0][0] or [1][1] or [2][2], nothing happens.

The following is my code, i am unable to get the final output as i think there there is something wrong with my swapping algorithm, any help is appreciated.

```
file =(input("Enter the filename: "))

f = open(file)
matrix = []



for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.split()

    if line:
        for x in range(len(line)):

            line[x] = int(line[x])

        matrix.append(line)

transpose = []

for x in range(len(matrix)):
    transpose.append([])
    bob = transpose[x]



    for y in range(len(bob)):
        temp = 0
        temp = matrix[x][bob[y]] 
        matrix[x][bob[y]] = matrix[y][bob[x]]
        matrix[y][bob[x]] = temp




print(matrix)
print(transpose)
```

Comment: What is the question? Does your code work? what does/doesn't it do that is incorrect?  What is the expected output for the example input?

Comment: “So the value of list [0][1] should change from 2 to 1”: isn’t it from 3 to 1?

Comment: yes ur right, it should change from 3 to 1, slight typo sorry about that. And my question is how to fix the swapping algorithm as i am unable to get the final output

Comment: the expected output from the example input should be [[2,1,9],[3,2,8],[4,6,9]]

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this could be replaced by a `zip()` function pretty easily.  Passing in 3 separate arrays (list[0], list[1], list[2]) and zipping them will basically realign the elements by column.  So [[2 3 4], [1 2 6], [9 8 9]] becomes [[2 1 9], [3 2 8], [4 6 9]].

```
>>> lista = [2,3,4]
>>> listb = [1,2,6]
>>> listc = [9,8,9]
>>> new = zip(lista, listb, listc)

>>> for row in new:
...     print(row)

(2, 1, 9)
(3, 2, 8)
(4, 6, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
>>> list(zip(*matrix))
[(2, 1, 9), (3, 2, 8), (4, 6, 9)]
>>>
```

Comment: may you explain what the function zip() does and what *matrix does for the zip function?

Comment: I included a link to `zip`'s documentation in my post.  `matrix` is the list of lists that you constructed from the file in your example. the `*` unpacks the *sub*-lists from `matrix`.

Answer (score -1):

Other more *traditional* methods can be found [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/transpose-matrix) especially matrix transpose using nested loops.

Comment: Please mention why answer is not helpful in comments when you downvote